# Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination buttons are not clickable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am having a problem with my UI Pagination, The Pagination loads on my page but none of the buttons are clickable. Has anyone had this problem? Here is my code.

```
<div class="rs-agency">
    <!-- Real estate agency details -->
    <div class="agency-item" ng-repeat="Review in Reviews.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage))">
        <!-- Name -->
        <h4><a href="#">{{Review.ReviewName}}</a></h4>
        <!-- Address -->
        <!-- Contact details -->
        <!-- About Agency -->
        <p>{{Review.ReviewContent}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-color btn-sm">{{Review.ReviewDateTime}}</a>
    </div>
    <pager total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="ItemsPerPage"></pager>
</div>
```

Angular JS Code

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:62012/api/RestaurantReviews/getReviewByRestaurant/' + ID
}).success(function (response) {

    $scope.Reviews = response;
    TotalItems = $scope.Reviews.length;

    //Pagination
    $scope.totalItems = TotalItems;

    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;

    $scope.maxSize = 5;
}).error(function (err) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo of the HTML.

```
<pager total-items="totalItems" 
        ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="ItemsPerPage">
</pager>
```

Should be:

```
<pager total-items="totalItems" 
       ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="itemsPerPage">
</pager>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works now. Gotta watch those typos lol